# Can we have a tool-tip with the full title for links to hot meta posts that don't fit into the side bar?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, community-bulletin

When browsing Stack Overflow, sometimes I will look at the Hot Meta Posts on the pinned area to the right of the current question. Unfortunately, some questions have very long titles, and so their titles get cut off.

Example:

[image]

Sometimes, this is solved by simply hovering over the link and looking at the browser's URL tool-tip at the bottom of the viewport (in Firefox; don't remember off the top of my head how other browsers handle it). Other times, however, even this tool-tip is incomplete, due to how the website creates URLs based upon question titles.

My screenshot didn't capture my mouse cursor, but it's hovering over the circled and underlined link. I would like for a tool-tip with the full text of the question's title to appear just as it does when hovering over similar links (such as links in the "Similar Questions" box that appears when writing a question). At the very least, a tool-tip with an *expanded* limit would be nice.

Comment: Easily implementable , so yea upvote

Comment: Nice idea + 1 from me too !

Comment: Tooltip example: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ubAfu.png

Comment: I really wish this has a longer title so that it would be an example of this issue... that would be more appropriate for a meta discussion

Comment: @Thymine That would indeed be a good example. Unfortunately I had "short title" in mind when drafting it.

Comment: @Thymine It now does. Someone just needs to make a tooltip image now

Comment: @Thymine Looks like Bergi has you covered ;-)

Comment: Now it is a meta-meta feature (;

Comment: I never learn: I always mouse over the truncated titles hoping to see the full title in a tooltip. I'd be so pleased if this started working one day.

Comment: When would it be helpful to not implement this? I cannot think of a reason, I agree with this suggestion.

Comment: are there many large titles to implement this feature ? though it's simple

Comment: @niceman One title is enough of a reason, to be honest.

Comment: @TylerH with that simple yes, but if it was hard , one title wouldn't be enough :)

Comment: Agree with OP, a must have feature

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Added to the next build. Sorry that this fell through the cracks (and thanks for [calling it out](https://twitter.com/Tyler_Hibbard/status/631902947614564352)), this was indeed an easy no-brainer.

Comment: Thanks again! I don't usually target Stack Exchange devs individually... I promise!