# MCVE page should mention Stack Snippets

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-snippets, help-center

Currently the Stack Overflow [MCVE page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) doesn't mention Stack Snippets. It really, really should, e.g. as a new paragraph just under the initial set of bullet points:

> If your question is about HTML, CSS, and/or JavaScript, it may be possible to create a live example of the problem using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/stack-snippets/info) (the `<>` editor toolbar button), which ensures all of the relevant information is on-site and makes it really easy for people to see the problem and answer your question. Here are some [detailed instructions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for creating snippets.

Related:

- [*Add StackSnippets to the how-to-ask page?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306199/add-stacksnippets-to-the-how-to-ask-page)
- [*Add information on Stack Snippets to Help Center*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277340/add-information-on-stack-snippets-to-help-center)

Comment: Stack snippets are currently terrible. This discussion already happened before and many agreed with me that if users feel obliged to use a broken feature it might deter them from posting at all, or have negative effect on the quality of their post. I don't have the guts to start meta post about how many issues need to be fixed - last time I proposed improvement I was downvoted to hell and advised to use external editor or jsfiddle.

Comment: Here's the deleted post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310536/607407 here is the prewious discussion on this topic: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315235/607407

Comment: @TomášZato: Your deleted post asking that Stack Snippets proactively save your changes as you type got a grand total of two downvotes; hardly "downvoted to hell." The other is about making it easier to explain Stack Snippets, and seems well-received. Neither is an argument against the above. I agree that Stack Snippets needs work and I'm **very** frustrated by how it's been ignored (even [really simple things like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239706/134069), but there's lots more that needs doing). That's not a reason for not suggesting using them. It's a reason for improving them.

Comment: This boils down to opinion. My opinion is that promoting broken feature makes site look worse. Broken features should be accessible for those who want to give them a try, and possible provide feedback later on, but not promoted as valid part of the site. People should not feel that stack snippets are compulsory.

Comment: @TomášZato: Agreed re opinion. I don't think Stack Snippets are broken. I think they could be improved (a *lot*), and I think it's appalling that they've been allowed to sit around for so effing long unloved while development resources are spent building silly games instead. But they're not *broken*. :-)

Comment: Having two snippets in your post makes writing almost impossible due to weird lag they cause. Long code causes part of the code to be invisible in the editor and you can't scroll to it. You lose your code if endless loop happens as I mentioned in the linked post. Those are **critical issues** that make them really hard to use. When I used them I always used external editor for both snippets and the post itself (due to aforementioned lag).

Comment: @TomášZato: Maybe we should team up building a comprehensive set of feature-requests and bug reports, and a meta-question listing them, see if we can achieve critical mass.

Comment: This is a post where you can see all the mentioned problems live: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33309300/607407 that was the last time I bothered to use Stack snippets.

Comment: @TomášZato: Nice answer! I get no lag if I open that and start editing. (I do routinely get lag in long answers even *without* Stack Snippets). But I don't want to turn this into an ongoing conversation; we should report bugs and missing features, and collect them into a meta-question listing them. I can't today, but maybe if we do that we can get critical mass.

Comment: @TomášZato I find snippets very simple and useful. I've dumped jsfiddle and codepen entirely.

Comment: @TomášZato I was going to comment I had no problems with the stack snippet of your post, but then it hid by itself while I was scrolling. But usually I don't have problems (except [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295666/1529630) which I had to fix with an userscript).

Comment: With the exception of one script with complicated event handing, Stack Snippets have always worked as they should when I posted JavaScript. Maybe I'm easily pleased, but I'm impressed that SO got this feature to work so well. I personally think it's one of the best features of SO. An answer with code that you can see in action is so much more instructive, especially for inexperienced programmers.

Comment: It is true that the quality of Stack Snippets is an opinion, and on that same train of thought, "Stack Snippets are terrible" is hardly a defensible position. They work demonstrably well for thousands of HTML, CSS, and JS questions already. Yes there are probably some bugs out there if you are using them to write complicated, not-actually-minimal JavaScript snippets, but they are far down the long tail.

Comment: Over a year later, this **quick, easy thing** still isn't done. C'mon, folks, let's help people post good questions!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not saying I advocate this method, but in the past I have had luck in a similar situation by [pinging a dev directly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302496/2756409)...

Comment: @TylerH: :-) Nice. I don't really tweet, perhaps you'd try to replicate your success?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder These days I'd probably try pinging on MSE in the Tavern first...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I frankly don't think it's sufficient, but I just looked and the page does have this now:

> - Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to include runnable HTML, JavaScript or CSS.

So in some minimalist way, this may be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) now.

Comment: oh yeah... I added this a while back in response to [a different answer of yours](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380194/can-we-please-get-the-how-to-create-an-mcve-help-page-updated-to-state-that-a/380260#380260)

Comment: @Shog9 Eugh, where is the serial comma in that list?!

Comment: *Slaps Tyler upside the head with a wet Oxford*

Comment: @Shog9 ...to give him the missing Oxford he's asking for? :-)

Comment: @TylerH Fixed, because what is this diamond good for if not [to keep us from all seeing things we don't want to see](https://i.imgur.com/ZxU8R6Z.jpg).