# I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?

Tags: discussion, faq, answers, asking-questions, stack-snippets

Sometimes when asking a question or posting an answer related to HTML, CSS, and/or JavaScript, I've been told to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve) using Stack Snippets. How do I do that? The "Code" help in the editor doesn't say anything about it, and I don't see anything in the [advanced editing help](/editing-help) either.

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/)

---

*(This question is a non-React version of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support), since Stack Snippets are still under-documented and the [announcement for them](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) is markedly out-of-date.)*

Comment: Related feature request: [*Add detailed help for Stack Snippets to the editor's “Code” section and the advanced help*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302960/add-detailed-help-for-stack-snippets-to-the-editors-code-section-and-the-adva)

Answer (score 288, accepted):

Stack Snippets are an on-site tool similar to [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net), [codepen.io](https://codepen.io) or [plnkr.co](https://plnkr.co). They're more limited than those tools, but they have the advantage of being on-site, so your code/markup is **in** your question (or answer), not just linked, and so it's accessible even if the off-site location isn't, and people don't have to go off-site to help you / get help from you.

They were announced and initially documented in [this SE blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), but it's markedly out of date now.

In a snippet, you provide your HTML and/or CSS and/or JavaScript, and then it can be run with a click of a button, with the result shown in your post.

**Note:** Snippets are for **runnable** examples in the browser demonstrating a problem. If your snippet code isn't going to be **runnable** in the browser (see Steps 3 and 4 below), don't use a snippet; just highlight it and use the `{}` button (or <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>) — or indent each line with four spaces — to format as a code block instead.

This answer covers snippets generically. Some libraries or technologies have their own answers tailored specifically to them:

- [React, including JSX](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538)
- [Vue2, convert component to runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417270/1712345)
- [Vue3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419282/1712345)
- (Please feel free to add others here as they're written...)

### Basics

You can add a Stack Snippet either by using the built-in editor GUI or by adding the `<!-- begin snippet -->` (with optional options) and `<!-- end snippet -->` comments manually, with HTML and/or CSS and/or JavaScript sections between them.

#### Editor GUI

To create a snippet:

1. Open the Stack Snippets editor, either by clicking the [image: [<>]] toolbar button or, with the cursor in the answer box, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd>:

   [image: screenshot of the editing panel with snippets button highlighted]

That will give you a pop-up dialog with controls on the left and four panes on the right:

[image: screenshot of snippets editor]

2. Enter your HTML, CSS, and/or JavaScript, putting each (with no wrapper) in its labelled pane. Don't put a `<html>...</html>` or `<body>...</body>` tag around your html, `<script>...</script>` tag around your JavaScript or `<style>...</style>` tag around your CSS; that will be done for you. Just put them in the correct pane. (Note that putting non-`body` content in the HTML panel will produce **invalid** HTML in the snippet when run. It may mostly work, but at best it'll be misleading.¹)

   - If your code needs [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)), you can simulate it with [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) and static data.
   - If you need to show that [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) isn't preventing the default of following a link, see [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387019/how-do-i-demonstrate-a-preventdefault-problem-on-a-link-in-a-stack-snippet) about how to do that (since Stack Snippets won't let you navigate to a different document or open a new window). (TL;DR - Use a link to a fragment identifier.)
   - If your code needs [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), those aren't supported by Snippets, but you can use a fake version like [this one](https://heretic-monkey.link/FauxStorage.js) from [Heretic Monkey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey).
3. When you've put in your HTML, CSS, and/or JavaScript, click the **Run** button to make sure the snippet shows what you want it to show in the Result pane.
4. Make sure your code is properly and consistently formatted. (You can use the **Tidy** button in the editor to have it apply its rules to your code if you like.)
5. When the snippet works, demonstrating what you're trying to show, and the code is properly and consistently formatted, click **Save & insert into post** to save it to the text of your post and close the snippet editor. (You can always reopen it later by clicking the **edit the above snippet** link under the snippet.)

#### Manually

If you are creating/editing a post from an environment that lacks the editor GUI (for example, when submitting posts [via the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write) or mobile devices), it might be useful to know how to build a snippet manually.

The rules for creating a snippet this way are pretty simple:

1. Open with an HTML comment: `<!-- begin snippet: js [...options] -->`
2. Add up to 3 "sections" representing HTML, CSS, and JavaScript parts of the snippet by prefixing each section with a comment: `<!-- language: lang-<js|css|html> -->` (there is no need for all 3 sections to be present)
3. Close with an `<!-- end snippet -->` comment

External libraries are added via `<script src="<HTTPS link>">` tag and thus require a `<!-- language: lang-html -->` section to be present.

Options of the `begin-snippet` are added as space-separated `name: value` pairs. The following options are available (circa 2021):

| Name | Required | Values | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `babel` | no | Boolean | Transpiles JavaScript if `true` |
| `console` | no | Boolean | Disables built-in console if `false` or missing |
| `hide` | no | Boolean | Collapses the snippet if `true` |

### Details

#### The Panes

The four panes in the snippet editor are:

- **HTML** - The top-left pane. Only the `body` content goes here. When you run the snippet, it will be wrapped in markup including `<body>...</body>` tags (regardless of whether it belongs in `body` or not).¹
- **CSS** - The top-right pane. Your CSS goes here, as though it were in a stylesheet or a `<style>...</style>` element (which is where it will go).
- **JavaScript** - The bottom-left pane. Your JavaScript goes here. When the snippet is rendered, this will be in a `<script>..</script>` element at the end of the `<body>`, **after** any HTML you've included.
- **Result** - The bottom-right pane. Your snippet is rendered here.

#### Actions

- To run the snippet, click **Run**
- To pass the code and markup through a "pretty-printer", click **Tidy**
- To **completely** wipe out the code and settings in the snippet editor, click **Reset**
- To leave the editor without saving the snippet to your post, click **Cancel**

#### Including libraries, etc.

If the library you want to use is listed in the dropdowns on the left, just pick it from the dropdown; the editor will insert a `<script>` tag (or tags) in the HTML for that library. You can always edit or remove it later.

To include a library or stylesheet that isn't listed, you can use the **Add an external library** button and provide a URL; the editor will then automatically add either a `<script>` or a `<link>` tag for it in the HTML pane. Typically you'd source these from a CDN like https://cdnjs.com.

#### AJAX

If your code needs AJAX, you can simulate it with `setTimeout` and static data. Instead of:

```js
fetch("/some/resource")
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
    // ...use data here...
})
.catch(/*...*/);
```

you'd do:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    // ...use data here...
}, 800);
```

or if you need a promise:

```js
return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 800, {/*...data here...*/}));
```

#### Console

By default, an in-snippet console will be included, so that `console.log` and similar statements generate output to the result pane. This involves adding console-specific CSS and markup to your snippet, which in some relatively-rare cases may interfere with what you're trying to show. If you don't intend to use `console.log` and such, untick the box. If you do, though, it's very handy to have those results shown in the result pane rather than hidden away in the browser's console.

The console is limited to only the bottom of the result window. If your **only** output is to the console, you can force that area to fill the window by adding this CSS (sadly, there is no actual option for doing this):

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

The console also by default limits to 50 entries. You can disable that limit using this JavaScript:

```js
console.config({
    maxEntries: Infinity
});
```

...or, of course, use your own limit by supplying a number other than 50. Here's an example that limits the console to five entries:

```js
console.config({
    maxEntries: 5
});
let i = 0;
const handle = setInterval(function() {
    ++i;
    console.log(`Entry #${i}`);
    if (i === 10) {
        clearInterval(handle);
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
Watch the console, it's been restricted to 5 entries; once it reaches 5, older ones start dropping off as newer ones are added.
```

[canon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/159427/canon), who wrote the snippet console, [added some other options years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239456/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here/279495#279495), but they don't appear to have been deployed to the SE network, and [no UI for the options exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284754/implement-a-ui-for-the-stack-snippet-console-options).

#### Transpiling

By default, your code is run "as is" in the browser. But if you tick the **Use BabelJS / ES2015** checkbox, your code will be *transpiled* using the in-browser version of [Babel](https://babeljs.io). This isn't needed much anymore as all major browsers support the vast majority of ES2015+, but you'd use it for a React snippet for example.

#### Showing / Hiding By Default

By default, when you insert your snippet in a post, it will show the content of the snippet. Often that's exactly what you want: to show your code. But if you're doing a snippet that's just a live example of code blocks you've already written, or demonstrating minor tweaks to a previous snippet, etc., you may not want it to take up that much space. If so, tick the **Hide snippet by default** checkbox.

#### Example

Here's an example snippet with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, loading an external library (jQuery):

```js
$(".container").text("Hello, Stack Snippets!");
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #02F;
  color: #02F;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Notice that:

- Our JavaScript is added to the resulting page **after** the markup in our HTML pane (if it weren't, the snippet above wouldn't show anything because the `<div>` wouldn't be there when the code ran).
- We don't have a `<script>` tag around our JavaScript (it's added for us)
- We don't have a `<style>` tag around our CSS
- In this case, we **didn't** tick the **Hide snippet by default** checkbox, so the snippet's code is shown
- Since we weren't using the console, we unticked the **Show console** checkbox

Here's that exact same snippet, but with the **Hide snippet by default** checkbox ticked:

```js
$(".container").text("Hello, Stack Snippets!");
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #02F;
  color: #02F;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And here's a JavaScript-only snippet using `console.log`:

```js
console.log("Hello, Stack Snippets!");
```

---

¹ About putting non-`body` content in the HTML pane: Beware that Stack Snippets literally just take when you put there and dump it out in their generated `body` tag. So for example, suppose your HTML panel content were this:

```html
<head>
    <title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body class="x" onload="console.log('hi there')">
    <p>My Paragraph</p>
</body>
```

What actually gets done by Stack Snippets at runtime is this invalid HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><!-- generated snippet head --></head>
<body><head>
    <title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body class="x" onload="console.log('hi there')">
    <p>My Paragraph</p>
</body>
<script>/* code from script pane here */</script>
<!-- optional console snippet div here -->
</body>
</html>
```

What the browser does with that is largely up to the browser, although the specification has some rules for handling invalid HTML. The result you get in Chromium browsers and Firefox as of this writing is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><!-- generated snippet head --></head>
<body class="x" onload="console.log('hi')">
    <title>Something</title>
    <p>My Paragraph</p>
<script>/* code from script pane here */</script>
<!-- optional console snippet div here -->
</body>
</html>
```

It's nice to see them putting the attributes of the invalid nested `body` on the main `body`, but as far as I can tell [that's not specified behavior](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inbody). Note that the `head` elements were not put in `head`, and most `head` elements are meaningless when they are dumped out to `body` instead.

So again, including only the *contents* of a `body` tag to avoid invalid and potentially misleading content in the Stack Snippet at runtime.

Comment: Also DO use the snippet editor EVEN when it is not runnable. Hit TIDY, Insert the snippet and **remove** the `<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->` before saving the question/answer - that will make it a code block

Comment: I built a class that imitates the storage API here: https://heretic-monkey.link/FauxStorage.js if anyone needs it. The advantage over a `Map` is that it casts incoming values as strings, just as localStorage does.

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey, I was thinking the same thing (given that recent question). Now the challenge is how to persist the information across snippet runs when we can't...persist information across snippet runs. Or otherwise make it possible for a novice to create a snippet that loads its logic twice, etc., without losing them in the complexity. I mean, it's not that complex, but if you're already flummoxed by a problem, it could be the last straw. I was thinking a snippet template they could use with "YOUR HTML GOES HERE" and "YOUR JAVASCRIPT GOES HERE" but I had to get back to work... :-|

Comment: Sadly, code snippets are not runnable on small screens (mobile devices).

Comment: Aren't they? They do run on my mobile, only the interface to add them ia missing.

Comment: @Noam it depends - they are not runnable on my device, for example. However, that is only a limitation in movile view - with the desktop spoofing option turned on, they become runnable again.

Comment: Proposed canonical link: ```[Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) (icon looks like `<>` on the editor toolbar)```

Comment: I routinely violate the instructions here by including a body element. This is often because 1) the script or CSS specifically targets it and I want it apparent that it's present, or 2) there's a valid reason for a head element in the snippet and I want that distinction apparent, or I don't want the auto-body wrapping it.

Comment: @isherwood - Just beware it's problematic and may be misleading, because any snippets you do that in are producing invalid HTML and are subject to the whims of the browser's interpretation of it. Stack Snippets literally just take the entire contents of the HTML pane and dump it out as the contents of a `body` tag, so you end up with a `head` inside a `body` and ` body` inside a `body`. I've added a note at the end to explain what happens, so people can make their own decision whether to do it (though I recommend not :-) ).

Comment: I'm aware, and that was sort of my point--improvements could be made to the snippet application.

Comment: @isherwood - OMG yes. Sadly, SE Inc shows no interest in doing anything about it. There's an incomplete list of things that are problematic and need fixing here: [*Please Fix Stack Snippets*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400732/please-fix-stack-snippets). (Why incomplete? Because with total silence from SE Inc, it's not worth my time trying to keep it up to date.)