# I need some help with improving my question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: *[Content.jsp is displayed in a small left top corner area, not full of the page with white background. How do I set the CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257549)*

Is my question not clear? Or are my words wrong? If it is, can anybody correct it?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow has partnered with Imgur to provide an image sharing solution (available by clicking on the picture icon in the editor toolbar). That allows us to put the image within the question, rather than making potential answerers go to a different page.

Comment: You might also take a look at [using a Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make it easier for others to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @HereticMonkey:  You *cannot* use a snippet for JSP.

Comment: @Makoto You can use it for the rendered HTML, and since that's what the question is ultimately about, I seem no problem with suggesting it.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure what exactly it is you're asking.  It's a little too scattershot to be one thing or another, so let's see if I can reverse engineer it.

- You have issues with HTML and CSS.
- You're using JSP.
- You're having problems with the combination of the three above.

...Problem with that is we don't really understand a lot of what the actual issue is.  You've got a link to an image but I'm not keen on clicking that right now.  Without any statement to say what issue you're having, then we're kind of stuck.

What you're going to want to do is explain the problem succinctly and concisely.  Don't rely on visual cues because that may put off others from actually helping you.

Comment: That image was on a dubious host, I grabbed it and uploaded it to imgur.

Comment: @rene thanks.  I'm not able to upload because my last questions reduced my reputation.

Comment: @Macoto I've edited  my question. Is it clear now?