# Is there a magic link for [snippet]?

Tags: feature-request, comments, stack-snippets, magic-links

Is there a page I can direct users to, giving information on how to create code snippets?

I've found [this one](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), but it's a bit old and doesn't reflect the current layout/options.

Is there a magic link available to that page... and if there isn't, can it be added for use with `[snippet]`?

And lastly, is there somewhere that lists current magic links available such as `[help]`, `[ask]` and `[mcve]`?

Comment: A list of magic links is being maintained [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000).

Comment: You can redirect them [to this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) for a snippet tutorial

Comment: T.J. Crowder was kind enough to [write a very detailed write up of how to create a snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552).

Comment: ["shorthand links"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) as they are called in the help center are available quite easily in every site you can comment by clicking the *help* button below the *Add Comment* one while typing your comment, then click on the [Learn more about formatting…](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) link in the popup that appeared. And for your feature-request, I guess the best would to convert T.J's post to an [help] page, so we can do `[help/snippet]` later on.

Comment: @Kaiido - can't believe I didn't even look in the comment help, I'm an idiot. But having `[help/snippet]` linking to TJ's excellent post would be great

Comment: @TylerH The edit you just made isn't asking the correct question. The question the OP was asking was "Can we add a magic-link for [snippet]?".

Comment: @JL2210 To be fair, it's both. I think it's obvious enough that it's implied in the question and tag that it's requesting one despite the title only asking if there currently "is" one. That's a better route, IMO, because if the title can be answered with "yes", then the FR in the body and as a tag are not even necessary.

Comment: @TylerH the question you kept was just a mean to ensure the FR was necessary, but your edit made this question a [discussion] one + this question had already been answered 3 times in the comments before your edit...