# Should Guided Mode allow snippets?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, stack-snippets, ask-question-wizard-2018

Currently new users are led to *guided mode* to ask their question. *Guided mode* does not have an option to add a Stack Snippet. I have a feeling, at least for JavaScript/HTML/CSS questions, this leads to more questions that don't have enough code to *reproduce the problem in the question itself*.

Should guided mode have the option to insert a Stack Snippet?

I have a feeling there are basically two minds on snippets. One is JavaScript/HTML/CSS answerers who all lean toward snippets being close to, but not quite, mandatory. Everyone else couldn't care less about snippets.

SO say an MCVE is required for debugging help. In my experience 90% of JavaScript/HTML/CSS questioners (new to Stack Overflow) don't know how to create a MCVE or even a CVE (not minimal) so, even if they leave a JSFiddle, their question is off-topic since the code required to reproduce the issue is not in the question itself.

This is exacerbated by the fact that guided mode doesn't even give them the option to add a snippet.

[image: guided mode]

Would adding a snippet option in guided mode (maybe only if the tag includes JavaScript, HTML, or CSS?) lead to more on-topic questions?

Comment: Do new users actually know how to use snippets? Even when they get the language right, I see far too many people use snippets for code that won't run, much less demonstrate whatever problem they have with it.

Comment: most of them know how to use jsfiddle since most of them post one, at least in the topics I watch, but end up leaving the question off topic by not knowing which part of their code is causing their issue. By suggesting a snippet at least there is a chance they'll post enough code in the question itself that it's more on topic. In other words encouraging them to use a snippet instead of jsfiddle more often then not lead to enough code in the question itself to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Laurel I knew how to use it when I was new. We shouldn't assume new users are stupid to the point of eliminating majorly helpful post features in guided mode.

Comment: It should at least be presented as an option so that people are aware it exists. If they don't know how to use the snippet editor it won't make a question any worse than it already is going to be.

Comment: If people in non-snippet runable tags are really against having code in snippets, then the snippet editor could be enabled as an option only if the OP adds a tag where it might be used. However, personally, I'd expect that having something that looks like a code editor would make it more likely for users to actually add code, which is a good thing, even if the code can't be run in a snippet. In other words, a snippet, if the code is not JavaScript/HTML/CSS, is just formatting with a convenient way to copy the code into an answer.

Comment: Does it *actually hurt* to have the OP use a snippet when the language is not JavaScript/HTML/CSS? I know some people don't like it, but is it that using a snippet *really* makes understanding the question/answering more difficult, or just offend people's sensibilities? Does it really give OP's the impression that their non-JavaScript/HTML/CSS code should be runable in the snippet? [Note: I'm not trying to be judgemental. If I was editing a non-JavaScript/HTML/CSS questions, I'd normally edit the snippet formatting out of it too.]

Comment: Also, can we fix that part about "code fences"? There's a hotkey for it, ctrl-K, and it does a *way* better job than three backticks (one, people screw up the extra blank line needed for things to work in the first place, and two, I saw someone use `'''` just the other day). Regarding snippets, way too many people paste C# code that get inserted as HTML, JavaScript, and on at least one occasion, *CSS.*

Comment: I actually don't see why this "guided mode" has no editor toolbar at all. To me, that makes editing a lot easier than reading the instructions about markdown in this uncomfortable block of text that is the help dropdown.

Comment: @Draco18s I disagree, I find the three backticks way easier to edit. Moreover, adding the language tag makes for better highlighting - the default will sometimes highlight variables as if they are keywords. Also, having three backticks and then start their code on the next line is bad but *super* easy to edit - literally hit enter. I'll counter with the fact I've seen many who have merged two unrelated code blocks because you can't avoid it, or have merged a code block and actual text that is part of the question. So it's not like Ctrl+K is flawless.

Comment: "don't have enough code to reproduce the problem in the question itself" That would be a problem if SO was a about getting your code debugged for free. But we don't actually want debugging questions anyway, because they help only the asker.

Comment: @VLAZ What part of CSS syntax highlighting helps a C# code block?

Comment: @Draco18s I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @VLAZ If you use the snippet box and put C# code in it and tell the snippet box that your code is CSS you get a `<--language: CSS-->` markup tag. See [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56044706/3). This is a type of edit I have to make [all the time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jxk5.png). I'm not against the snippet window, I just...want it to allow more sensible options so that people can say "this code is Python" or "this code is Lisp" and have the language markup tag *actually apply correctly.*

Comment: @Draco18s what does the snippet window have to do with a triple backtick comment block?

Comment: @VLAZ I was, obviously, replying to your `Moreover, adding the language tag makes for better highlighting` comment.

Comment: @Draco18s you can add the language tag to a triple backtick. Exactly as shown in the image in the OP. By contrast, if using the Ctrl+K method, you have to write a lot more for the same amount of functionality.

Comment: @VLAZ Or let the system handle it by using the post's tags, resulting in even less work (note: I've never seen anyone use a language tag with three backticks either). But my *primary* complaint is that the snippet editor is not as useful as the question makes it out to be. The part about the three backticks is that people screw it up more often than I've seen it done right. Are there issues with ctrl-K / four spaces? Sure. But not as many (the largest is people just not using *either* system).

Comment: @Makyen AFAIK, it contributes to noise and confusion at worst. Not sure of any bigger issues (maybe lack of proper syntax highlighting?

Comment: @TylerH Yeah, the inaccurate syntax highlighting is certainly of concern. However that could be easily solved by allowing the user to select from a drop-down the language that they are actually entering into the editor (and disables/hides the "Run code snippet" button if not JavaScript/CSS/HTML). Overall, I think having a dedicated interface that makes it clear the user is entering code is a significant benefit.

Answer (score 1):

As snippets are only for HTML javascript and CSS, a new user should learn how to use stack snippets within the question, instead of people telling them in comments. What I prefer is this

- The wizard should detect the language using the second tab (the tag tab).
- If the detected language is runnable on the stack snippet then the "show some code" block should mention about [how to create a stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) and what to put inside the stack snippet. Also, a button to create a stack snippet.

By this, new users can also learn how to create stack snippets and not use snippets for Java and PHP. Which also fulfills the purpose of the guided mode.