# Prompt new users to try Stack Snippets

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, new-users, editor, welcoming

I've been using SO for a fair while now and only just learned today about how to make Stack Snippets. My initial impression was that code entered into a message/post would automatically become a snippet. I was wrong, but I couldn't understand why my code wasn't becoming a snippet. It was only after searching the internet today that I discovered it's something you need to do manually.

There needs to be a way of showing new users how to use this functionality. It's very confusing and frustrating having no prompting. If there was prompting I did not notice it.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386147/should-guided-mode-allow-snippets

Comment: Stack-Snippets are only relevant to some tags (web-front related generally). This prompt might actually be noise for someone that is asking about say haskell.

Comment: Worse than noise. I've seen people use them for languages that aren't supported and get the wrong syntax highlighting and extra buttons. If we add a notification, we could make it exclusive to questions only using supported language tags.

Comment: @Kaiido Perhaps there could be a way of prompting the user after they've entered valid code as a code block?

Comment: Yes it could be added only on questions that have some tags like [css] [html] or [javascript]. However, I still feel the "Guided Mode" would be a better place for such an introduction.

Comment: @Kaiido I must have skipped "Guided Mode" because I have no idea what that is.

Comment: When you are about to [compose a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), there is a link at the top ["Use guided mode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?guided=true). I think most new users are presented with this mode now, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Kaiido every user < 111 reputation gets the Ask Question Wizard: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live

Comment: There is an *faq* on how to create a snippet. Whenever someone posts code that is *runnable* or posts a jsfiddle, you can add a comment pointing them to this post: [I've been told to create a “runnable” example with “Stack Snippets”, how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: Having something become a snippet when it isn't a language that's actually snippetable is annoying to no end.  Especially since there is 0 chance I would ever run a snippet (just a virus waiting to happen).  I do not want more accidental snippets appearing in the tags I answer.

Comment: @GabeSechan It wouldn't have to automatically become a snippet. I was suggesting that new users be made better aware of this functionality.

Comment: @JossClassey To those of us who don't write Javascript, the snippet function is a negative to the site, not something we really want increased use of.  Especially by new users who won't realize that the feature won't work on their question.  Really combined with that and the security implications I'd rather see snippets die.

Comment: @gabeSechan wich security implications?

Comment: @JonasWilms Running random code from random people sounds like a bad idea.  I wouldn't do it, ever.

Comment: @GabeSechan Stack Snippets are safe; they run in very sandboxed iframes. Pretty sure the worst thing they could do is continually consume CPU, which is easily fixed by reloading the tab the snippet is on. As someone who continually browses Javascript questions and runs any snippet whose problem (or solution) I'm interested in seeing, I've never encountered a problem. The *inappropriate* use of Stack Snippets on questions not related to frontend is the (significant) problem.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm sure they try to make it safe.  But I don't want, and will not accept the additional threat vector, and I think its a bad idea for anyone else to.  You're welcome to your own opinions on that.