# How do I demonstrate a preventDefault problem on a link in a Stack Snippet?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

I need to demonstrate a problem with using `preventDefault` to prevent following a link, but Stack Snippets won't let me have a link that navigates to another page or opens a new window. So how do I demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 34):

Although Stack Snippets prevent you navigating to a *different* document (or opening a new window), you can navigate *within* a document using a fragment identifier, which is all you need to demonstrate `preventDefault`:

```js
const cbPreventBottomLink = document.getElementById("prevent-bottom");
document.querySelector("a[href='#bottom']").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (cbPreventBottomLink.checked) {
        console.log("prevented");
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        console.log("not prevented");
    }
});
```

```css
.tall {
    height: 75vh;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="tall">
    <div>
        <a href="#bottom">Click for #bottom</a>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="prevent-bottom">
            Use <code>preventDefault</code> to avoid following #bottom link.
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="bottom" class="tall">
    div with id="bottom"
    <div>
        <a href="#">Back to top</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Side note: Since clicking the links above is navigating in an iframe (containing the snippet) within this MSO page, the navigation gets added to the history used by the Back button of the browser. So if you click the links above (without preventing default), then click the Back button, it navigates back to the previous link within the iframe. To actually go back to where you were before coming to this page you have to click through those navigations. That's completely standard behavior, but nevertheless could be surprising as our mental model tends to separate snippets from the page as a whole.

Comment: Navigating within a Stack Snippet iframe pollutes the browser history. I'm not sure whether it would be worth SO trying to prevent that or not. I certainly found it confusing for a second whilst trying to leave the page.

Comment: @Turnip - Oh, wow, wild. It's normal behavior, but it probably defies our mental model. I've added a note. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the CSS for it to work. Just going to a blank page seems unclear, but it could be fine depending on the example being demonstrated.

Answer (score 6):

You can actually make StackSnippets navigate to other documents, though they need to not be on an other domain.
So to demonstrate the use of `Event.preventDefault` on an anchor's click, you can simply set your anchor's `href` to point to StackSnippet's *404* page using the quite commonly understood `/foo` url:

```js
document.querySelector('a').onclick = (evt) => {
  if(document.querySelector('input').checked) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log('prevented');
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="/foo">go to /foo</a><br>
<label>preventDefault <input type="checkbox"></label>
```

Also note that you can even navigate to documents from which you can control the content:

```js
const html_content = `<html><body><h1>Hey you got there!</h1></body></html>`;
document.getElementById('blob_user').href = URL.createObjectURL(  
  new Blob([html_content], {type: 'text/html'})
);
```

```html
<a href="data:text/html,<h1>Hello%20world</h1>">go to an Hello World html document</a><br>
<a id="blob_user">go to an html document generated by JavaScript</a>
```