# Snippet with react-router-dom routing

Tags: support, bug, stack-snippets

I'm trying to run this snippet here on Stack Overflow.

I'm using `react-router-dom` from a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network). I'm able to match the first route, but somehow I can't change to a different route.

Is it possible to simulate routing like this using the snippet? This same scripts works on jsFiddle.

Am I doing something wrong?

```js
const { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link } = window.ReactRouterDOM;

function App() {

  return(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/js" component={Home}/>
        <Route exact path="/js/comp1" component={Component1}/>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

function Home(props) {
  console.log('Rendering Home...');
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>I am home</div>

      <div>props.location.pathname: {props.location.pathname}</div>
      <div>props.match.path: {props.match.path}</div>

      <Link to='/js/comp1'>Component1</Link>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Component1(props) {
  console.log('Rendering Component1...');
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>I am Component1</div>

      <div>props.location.pathname: {props.location.pathname}</div>
      <div>props.match.path: {props.match.path}</div>

      <Link to='/js'>Home</Link>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/5.0.1/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: What is this `react-router-dom` you speak of? [DOM bindings for React Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-dom) (GitHub)? npm package?

Comment: Probably not, since it has to do with changing the URL, and I don't think the snippet iframe allows navigation. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387019/215552 for instance.