# How can I add JSON content in a formatted way in a Stack Overflow question/answer?

Tags: discussion

I am trying to post JSON content in a Stack Overflow question, but it displays in a single line and want it in a formatted way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#link-code

Comment: I think it's available here                                                                                                                                                                                         [Answer to How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: You need to format it yourself, in an editor. on SO there are no fancy formatting features as many programming languages and formats have their own needs, not to speak about tabs vs spaces .... see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149635/json-editor-formatter and if you need extra suggestions this search might help: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=format+JSON+editor+is%3Aq+answers%3A1&mixed=0

Comment: Paste the JSON in a stack snippet and click on *"Tidy"*: [How do I create a Stack Snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)