# How do you ask a question with a code snippet?

Tags: discussion, design

I see a header with formatting tips but nothing for code snippets. Am I missing it?

Comment: You can also press `ctrl`+`m` to bring it up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets", how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Answer (score -3):

Should be something like this:
[image]