# Why was my question closed due to "lack of focus" when I've included code and a JSFiddle?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed, needs-more-focus

I asked [javascript iife doesn't work after refactoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66416129/javascript-iife-doesnt-work-after-refactoring) with some sample code, and it was closed due to "lack of focus".  What's that close reason and why would my question be closed for it?  Note that the images in the question are the *output* of the script and not the actual code itself.

Comment: _“Note that the images in the question are the output of the script and not the actual code itself.”_ — Clarify that **in your question** then.

Comment: @JeanneDark:  This time the dupe doesn't fit.  Feels like the original question came across a bit hostile but there's at least a legitimate question as to why the question was closed to begin with, for which I could see why since it read a bit unclearly.  Maybe some experts in JavaScript could weigh in on this one.

Comment: At first sight, I'd say that that MCVE is not M enough. You also say "this works", but "this" sits behind a link, not in the question itself. That's not ideal, although it shouldn't be a deal-breaker here. But the amount of code presented to debug can feel a bit "too much" for many users, who might feel you should have worked to produce a simpler version that reproduced the problem. Also, since since you are showing output that includes code, I would advise you to properly show that those captures represent **output**, not code, since on first inspection it can look confusing.

Comment: In the [revisions of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66416129/revisions), you personally have only edited in _“Are robots here ? My questions is clear :(”_. After the discussion on Meta, telling you how to edit the post, you decided to comment [_“why do you think I made 2 screenshots are you blind ? Oh my humans are already replaced by cyborgs :D”_](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxZay.png) on the question. Those were your only actions on the main question. You’re not listening to our advice and accuse us of being bots. With your unconstructive behavior, no progress can be made.

Comment: Let me be absolutely clear here - the accusations of users being "robots" are ***not OK***. Do not think that you can just insult us with non-curse words. Because that's clearly what you meant by "robots", "stupid AI", and "cyborgs". You're using this term in the sense that we are unable to think and try to dehumanize us. The fact that you think it's acceptable to act this way towards us is very concerning. I'd recommend spending less time just assuming everybody else as wrong and more time considering whether they maybe have a point.

Answer (score 5):

## Multiple problems

After a cursory look, it seems you have multiple problems you (might be?) asking about:

1. One of them is everything being one line in the second code, where as there are multiple lines in the first one. *
2. The syntax highlighting does not happen.
3. There is a ReferenceError in the second piece of code. Not sure if it is related to 2. or not.

So, that's three as a start. I don't know if there are more because you haven't specified what problems exactly you are facing.

The only and most detailed explanation is:

> But when I tried to refactor to do change innerHTML it doesn't work anymore

Based on this, the only way to figure it out *what* to answer is for the answerers to try and find out themselves all the differences between two programs.

* There are probably a few dupes for this but it can also be a typo type problem - there is a piece of CSS in the first piece of code that is not in the second one.

### How to remedy

Clearly explain what exact problems are you asking about. Do not make us guess. What if we guess wrong? That is not going to be a satisfying answer to you.

Also, try to narrow your question to one problem only. Sometimes you do get multiple issues and can only ask in bulk. However, from the above, at least 1. is trivially fixable. Maybe 3. as well - at the very least, it *hopefully* is not related to 2. but if it is, then you only really have one issue.

## Very large example programs

You have a 200+ LOC blocks, I do not feel motivated to work through all the functionality differences and find all potential problems. I suspect others are also reluctant to do that.

Reading and understanding *one* such application is not easy by itself. You give us two and expect us to find the differences. That is not even *double* the work, it's much more since we have to

- read and understand the first program
- read and understand the second program
- figure out what is the "correct" behaviour
- find the difference in behaviour
- isolate the problem(s)

This should ideally already be part of the question. No,

> I want to change div innerHTML dynamically before applying syntax highlight.

does not serve as a very useful description here.

### How to remedy

Try to make your example [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
I do not know if it is possible to reduce the 200 lines to something less but I suspect it is. We do not need the whole application - if you're asking about why

```css
.microlight {
    font-family : monospace;
    white-space : pre;
}
```

```html
<div class=microlight>
for (var i = 0; i&lt;=10; i++) {
    // say hello
    echo("hello");
}
</div>
```

has newlines while

```js
let div = document.querySelector(".test");
div.innerHTML = `for (var i = 0; i&lt;=10; i++) {
    // say hello 
    echo("hello");
}`
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

does not, then this is 15 lines of code *total* between the two.

I suspect other problems in the code can similarly be reduced to the bare essentials to highlight them.

## External code

Linking to the code externally is bad. Your first piece of code is entirely external. The second is on JSFiddle and in the question, at least.

Questions should be self-contained. Users should not have to visit an external site in order to see all the code or all details.

- links can go down. Future visitors (answerers and people seeking a solution alike) will be severely hampered if they cannot understand the entire question because a link is now not working.
- sites can be blocked. Basically the same as above but instead of the site being down for *everyone*, only some users might be unable to access it for any reason - ISP, firewall, or something different. The result is the same as above. Worth mentioning because I keep seeing people think some links are "durable" somehow. Probably because they do not go to a random blog but a higher profile website.

  - Wikipedia is a very prominent website and unlikely to go down. It widely seen as a universal resource. It was also *blocked in Turkey* for two and a half years between April 2017 to January 2020.

Right now only half the code is in your question.

### How to remedy

Include the code in the question. You can even [make a runnable Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) of the code. [I have already done that for the existing code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66416129/4).

## Code as images

You have images of code in your question and it is not immediately clear that these are actual output of your program. It seems like you have an image of your code. We do get *a lot* of questions where the asker just screenshots their code (or even takes a picture with their phone...).

### How to remedy

In the meta question you said:

> Note that the images in the question are the output of the script and not the actual code itself.

Which is something that belongs in the main question itself.

## Not enough explanation

I have mentioned this several times but it merits an entire point to itself. There is not enough explanation for:

- What you are trying to achieve?
- What the code is doing?
- What does not work?
- Any other relevant information?

### How to remedy

Add more details.

You can add comments in the code for any of the above. For example, you can comment that something works, so we do not need to analyse it. Or add comments around where the failure, so we can focus there.

From the help page:

> Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question.

Comment: Take into account that the warning about the screenshots being output and not code was not added by the OP, but by another user editing the question. It doesn't make this answer wrong in any way, simply to point out that the OP hasn't actually "said" anything about the code-in-image situation.

Comment: @yivi you're right - I didn't see the edit history.

Comment: No, not at all. The answer is still right, of course.

Comment: @yivi I'm now very unhappy after seeing the edit history...