# How to get an answer to an old question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I have a question that is pretty much exactly the same as this 9 year old question:

[how to have a static index column in slickgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834922/how-to-have-a-static-index-column-in-slickgrid)

The answer provided in this thread is not accepted. I also tried it out and it didn't work for me. What is the best way for me to get this question answered?

Should I post it myself?

In that case, will it get flagged as duplicate? SO's definition of duplicate answers is "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." Do not accepted answers count towards that? Especially if the answer is potentially wrong? (Just because it doesn't work for me doesn't automatically mean it's wrong)

I don't think I can put a bounty on the question because I am new to SO and I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could re-ask but this is the minimum quality standard your question has to adhere to:

- open with your problem statement. Link to the other question and explain your problem is similar and you tried that answer.
- make a proper high quality [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (as that is missing from the other question) and include it in your post. See: [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets", how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)
- show how you applied/used/embedded the existing answer in your solution
- Explain why you implemented the answer from that code that way (*I assume the formatter needs to be set on the Column property because ...* <sup>1</sup> etc. you get the idea)
- Explain what you would expect
- Explain what happened instead

  - Include Debugging results: see [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs)
- Include any errors/warnings (developer console!)
- Include other relevant posts/documentation (on Stack Overflow or elsewhere) that you researched and tried to solve your issue.
- Ask in the last sentence what you need help with.

Worth reading, if you haven't already: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [this external site](http://idownvotedbecau.se/).

---

1. I have no idea what I'm talking about.