# Why doesn't Stack Overflow have a REPL?

Tags: feature-request

As we all know, Stack Overflow is used by a lot of developers to find errors and assist other developers. Many times code is posted both by the person asking the questions and members of the community who respond.

Wouldn't it be much convenient if there was a secure, shared REPL where persons could run the code submitted by the developer with the problem and subsequently the code from the responses?

People will point out that the final code is running on a compiler or interpreter that is different than a REPL and thus may not give the exact results. However, I see this as a method to assist with collaboration, which will make people avoid posting screenshots just to show the outputs and would allow persons at a glance to see what the code is doing without having to open an IDE.

Any thoughts?

Comment: [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) do exist

Comment: What the heck is a REPL, and why should Stack Overflow have it? Can't you just run the code on your own computer? If you *need* to run it online, just about every language has an online compiler/interpreter; use Google to find one.

Comment: @CodyGray REPL is just a tool to immediately run code. Like the browser console (for JS). I don't believe SO should have it for all languages. Of course more languages that can use in runnable snippets would be welcome but also not essential.

Answer (score 20):

0. If you *need* a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) to explain your problem, you haven't decomposed it enough to the degree that the problem is [minimal or reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and you should address that.
1. Install your *own* [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) if you need it.
2. Not all languages or all language versions have [REPLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) (and yes, there are some of us that are stuck on Java 8).

Comment: So...you must know what a REPL is. Care to enlighten the rest of us?

Comment: I've added some enlightenment @CodyGray.

Comment: Oh, so, it's *the entire process of writing code*. Cool. Yeah, I already have that on my computer.