# Wondering why my pretty detailed question was closed for needing 'more details and clarity'

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [ReCAPTCHA v3 badge glitches between inline and bottom-right when I hover over it or my form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69601361/recaptcha-v3-badge-glitches-between-inline-and-bottom-right-when-i-hover-over-it)

All the advice for understanding more information on the reason a question was closed seems to be to just read the comments, but I didn't receive any comments or answers before it was closed so not really got much to work with. I tried editing it to add screenshots and links to documentation but it's been a few hours and it isn't receiving any more views so I doubt it's going to be re-opened (not sure how long you usually have to wait, but it's been a lot longer than the time it took to be closed in the first place). The only thing that comes to mind is that I'm missing code samples, but I'm not sure what code I could provide since it seems to be down to the ReCAPTCHA API and I don't want to just provide all of it since this code isn't in production yet and could have security flaws as I'm updating it that people could abuse. Any suggestions as to what detail I could add (or whether it can be re-opened) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where's your code? How can we help you debug if you don't include it?

Comment: Sure, *"isn't in production yet and could have security flaws"*, fine, but that puts us at a bit of an impasse. We can't help you with your code because you won't share it, and you can't share your code because it's not ready. Is there no way you can provide a modified version of your code with any potential security issues like API keys simply removed?

Comment: @Nick I mean, I did show some styling in the screenshots, but sure I can get what you mean. My hope was that I had done something wrong with ReCAPTCHA itself that causes this issue that someone would know about

Comment: @Nick I don't mean API keys by security flaws, I have that in a separate file. I don't know, I just have a lot of code on this and don't want to risk accidentally sharing a bit that could be abused later down the line

Comment: Code (including your styling) _must_ be in the question itself _as code_, not in the form of a picture or screenshot (although I don't guarantee doing that will be enough to have your post reopened, I'm not an expert on the subject and don't know if that alone provides enough context to fix it)

Comment: @Nick The styling isn't mine, though- the styling is set by ReCAPTCHA's JavaScript. Unless there's a way to compile all the styling on a website (after it has loaded, as to include styling added by JS) into one file through inspect element or something, I'm not sure what to do for that

Comment: Why not remove all the code that is proprietary until you have an *absolutely* minimal working example that does exactly the same thing and then post that? Also see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Where is the recommended place to share HTML/CSS code? On-site, CodePen, Hastebin..?

Comment: @hopperelec You can create a [code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwxZ0.png).

Comment: In a [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) which is linked from the other link I posted in my previous comment ;)

Comment: Alright, just wondering if it would be different for HTML since you would want to be able to easily see it (and because it's usually longer)

Comment: I've re-wrote the entire question with a minimal working example. That actually helped a lot as it seems to be a specific, odd line in my CSS that's causing it for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe take look at the the [Help Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q66PI.png). There's a lot of information there about how to use the site. There are longer versions of everything on meta too. For example the "Do not use signature, taglines, greetings, thanks and other chit chat" part of [Expected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) versus  [No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it)

Comment: One of the common misunderstandings is that Stack Overflow works like a help-site. It's not. It's a repository of Question/Answer. Like a wikipedia of sorts.

Comment: @Scratte Ah, alright. I understood the wikipedia-esque thing, but still thought you asked the questions as though it was a help site. I've edited the question to remove that type of stuff I had at the end

Comment: @hopperelec *"That actually helped a lot as it seems to be a specific, odd line in my CSS that's causing it for some reason"* - That's another good reason to work out the minimum code to reproduce the problem. You often fix it yourself! (or at least get some better search terms to find the solution)

Comment: @Nick Yes! Sadly, still not fixed it, though. I know how I _could_ fix it, but it means removing one of the cool styling effects I have for my form which I'd like to keep, and I'd still be interested in knowing how a simple filter causes hovering over a fixed-position element to move inline haha

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am one of the users who voted to close that question.

Why?

1. Because you must provide enough information on the question itself to recreate that problem. Guessing your problem and hoping for an answer is not the way the site works.
2. Please post actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here for details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). In your case, some  HTML and CSS is the better way to go.
3. This was your question state when it was closed: [Revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/a1ca78b2-fc11-4b8d-848f-469b36a4b5a6/view-source)

I recommend reading the [help center summary](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Writing the Perfect Question, a blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) by a well-known user.

Your edit will push the question into the reopen queue, where community members will eventually review your edited question and may cast a vote to reopen if they feel it now meets the site guidelines.

Comment: My request for it to be re-opened failed, it seems. However, I re-wrote the entire question to add more specific information and keep it a lot less vague, including a minimum working example that fully demonstrates it, so I'm not sure why it's still not considered detailed enough

Comment: Question have already 2 reopen votes. Be patient. It's take some time.

Comment: When I sent that, it said something like "... was edited and requested for reopen but failed for: Edit did not fix issues" but it seems it's been re-submitted for review or something?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256567/which-edits-push-closed-questions-to-the-reopen-review-queue ?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question