# "</script>" causing issues in code snippet editor

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

```js
console.log('</script>');
```

This would end up with this HTML:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log('
</script>
');
```

That means the string `"</script>"` cannot appear anywhere in the JavaScript code snippet. Even though it is generally safe for XSS attacks since the snippet is isolated in an iframe with a different domain. But this is quite annoying when demonstrating some cases that do need `"</script>"` in a string value.

It might not be a bug, but it would be nice if the JavaScript section had some sanitization or if it imported as an external script to bypass XSS issues.

Comment: This can't really be considered a bug, this is the same behaviour you'd get if used without stack snippets as well. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659749/script-tag-in-javascript-string

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I wouldn’t say this is the “intended behavior”. It can be circumvented by escaping HTML, or using a generated CDN js file (like CodePen) like the answer you have addressed, though.

Comment: Why should stack snippets escape and change user provided code? Also the generated CDN JS file strategy is probably not something that Stack Overflow would pick since that implies storing the JavaScript separately from the post markdown as well. In general this is simply how HTML parsing works, why do you think Stack Overflow should solve this?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I mean, if I want to point out having `</script>` in a inline JavaScript could cause issues, I would have written it in the HTML section within a proper `<script></script>` tag. We have a separated JavaScript section for a reason, do we? That’s also pretty standard for most of the websites that have live code snippet feature.

Comment: Maybe, but that should be a separate **feature request** (not bug report) for stack snippets to not use inline scripts. Something should be possible with data URLs if they want to keep it simple I believe.

Answer (score 5):

No, let's not change the behavior.

While there is some magic going on in a Stack Snippet that hides the implementation detail that the given JavaScript ends up inside a `<script>` tag, its behavior is consistent with the simplest way developers will use JavaScript on a page.

It would be utterly confusing when the shown Stack Snippet works as intended but the same code wouldn't work when used in a plain HTML page with the code inside a `<script></script>` block in the real world. I'll consider the `<script src="" />` to be the advanced use-case, not the default use-case. Given I prefer to author for all audiences, the not junior devs are able to translate from inline script to referenced script.

I even wonder if there are more fail cases except this specific one with the script closing tag? I can't come up with one but JavaScript is not my native language. In general I oppose adding features that optimize corner cases.

I do note that in [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) we explicitly explain what happens with your JavaScript:

> When the snippet is rendered, this will be in a `<script>`..`</script>` element at the end of the `<body>`

That FAQ might be a bit easier to discover but beyond that Stack Snippets serve their goal.

Comment: I agree with most of your opinions. But for "*It would be utterly confusing when the shown Stack Snippet works as intended but the same code wouldn't work when used in a plain HTML page with the code inside a `<script></script>` block in the real world*", I beg to differ. If I want to intentionally demonstrate how JavaScript works in `<script></script>` tag in an HTML file, I would have written it properly in the HTML section. In real life most JavaScript are imported as an external file, I doubt anyone write their JavaScript entirely in the HTML file.

Comment: So the JavaScript section should *mimic* an external .js file like most of the other similar tools rather than providing a hacky way to embed a `<script>` tag in the HTML files silently. Or at least allow user to have this behavior as an option.